# Logic analyser reads bits as if they are shifted left by 1 bit, what could be the issue?

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, spi, protocol

The logic analyser is from Hobby Electronics, and is being run on the PulseView software.

It is not reading the data correctly. All of the bits are shifted one to the left so everything is read incorrectly.

I tried changing the settings like clock phase/polarity but this didn't help.

**Additional information:**

I'm sending the data from an ESP32 slave to an ESP32 master (CHPOL = 0, CHPA = 0, msb-first, word size 8).

Here's what the signal looks like, I'm sending all 0x42s, it's reading as 0x84.

It should be this: 01000010
It's reading this: 10000100

[image]

This is the start of the transaction, here I tried to send a 0x01 but it read 0x03. The clock seems to be starting at the right time...

[image]

**EDIT:**

I am manually driving the CS LOW which means it is ready to transfer to the master. Please note, the sent data is being read correctly on the other end, it's just the logic analyser that is reading it incorrectly.

**EDIT2:**

As per the answers and comments below, the issue was due to the CS pin.

Comment: There is no reference from chip select edge in any of those pictured. Do you ever control chip select?

Comment: @Justme hello, the CS is pulled low before talking to a slave. I am doing this myself ahead of time.

Comment: Don't do that. Most likely that is the reason.

Comment: The logic analyzer is showing you the reality of what is happening on the wire.  It is your expectation which is incorrect.

Comment: @Justme yep... that was it.

Comment: What's odd is that typically the act of connecting/disconnecting any sort of load at all, nevermind a relay, to the pi 3v3 rail would cause a disturbance which crashes the pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where's the transition on CS?

The CS high-low transition is needed to ensure the master and slave are in sync. Without it the slave may receive the data but may not be aligned correctly.

Usually it is high between transactions with the CS being active low.

Comment: My receiver device reads the bytes correctly, it's just the logic analyser that seems to read it incorrectly. (please see my question edit for my comment on CS pin)